# Azure Data Factory V2: Custom Activity inside a If Condition activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm working on an Azure Data Factory V2 Pipeline but I having a problem when I try to execute a "*Custom activity*" inside an "*If Condition Activity*".

If I try to test my pipeline with "Test Run" button on the ADF's Web interface, this error appeare:

> {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Activity PPL_ANYFBRF01 failed: Invalid linked service reference. Name: LNK_BATCH_AZURE","target"...}

I'm sure that there is no error in the linked service reference's name. If I create a "Custom Activity" directly in my pipeline, it's working.

I think it can be a syntax error on my activity but I can't find it.

Here is my "If Condition Activity"'s Json template (the expression "@equal(0,0)" is just for testing purpose):

```
{
    "name": "IfPointComptageNotExist",
    "type": "IfCondition",
    "dependsOn": [
        {
            "activity": "PointComptage",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        },
        {
            "activity": "SousPointComptage",
            "dependencyConditions": [
                "Succeeded"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "typeProperties": {
        "expression": {
            "value": "@equal(0,0)",
            "type": "Expression"
        },
        "ifTrueActivities": [
            {
                "type": "Custom",
                "name": "CustomActivityTest",
                "linkedServiceName": {
                    "referenceName": "LNK_BATCH_AZURE",
                    "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                },
                "typeProperties": {
                    "command": "Batch.exe",
                    "resourceLinkedService": {
                        "referenceName": "LNK_BLOB_STORAGE",
                        "type": "LinkedServiceReference"
                    },
                    "folderPath": "/test/app/"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
},
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I've got exactly the same functionality, and in my case it does work.

Comment: I've relaunch my pipeline and it's working now. I think it was a bug with the previous version of ADF (the old UI). Thank you for your reply :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is now solved. I have recreate the pipeline and it's working now.

Regards,

Julien.